# Varchar to Date and Time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a column MyColumn and data type is Varchar (50) in sql server 2012. It stores dates, time, and other info. I can modify the query to generate only date and time rows but format has issues.

**Q1)** How can I change result from `20141213` to `12132014`. I used the below and it did not work. It only works when data type for MyColumn is `DATETIME` or related but with `Varchar` it won't work.

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), MyColumn, 110),'-','') from MyTable
```

**Q2)** MyColumn stores time as example `0815`. How can I include `semi-colon` to result as `08:15`?

Please assist. 
Thanks.

Comment: Store date/time values as `date` or `datetime`.  Don't try playing around with string formatting stuff when SQL has good support for the real datatype.

Comment: I would completely agree with @GordonLinoff. Use underlying SQL datatypes. Best regards,

Comment: So far I have solved Q2 by writing the following statement:
SELECT LEFT(MyColumn, 2) + ':' + RIGHT(MyColumn, 2);

Comment: And answer to Q1 is SELECT SUBSTRING(MyColumn, 5,2) + RIGHT(MyColumn, 2) + LEFT(MyColumn, 4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i will not recommend saving date in a string, you can save data type as Date or DateTime Datatype,

answer for Q1 is

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(MyColumn, 5,2) + RIGHT(MyColumn, 2) + LEFT(MyColumn, 4)
```

but remember its works only when your sting in YYYYMMDD format and if you change formating then wrong answer will come or may be get error
and answer for Q2 is

```
SELECT LEFT(MyColumn, 2) + ':' + RIGHT(MyColumn, 2)
```